# Russian em dash in macros

Tags: babel, russian

On sharelatex.com the Russian em dash works fine in document body, but does not work when used in macros. I tried to ask the support, they sent me here.

[Sample project](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/584efa0e94faaf2e6db97d78)

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\foo{
qwe "--- rty
}

\begin{document}

\foo

asd "--- fgh

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: With out having tested it, what happens if foo is defined after begin doc? Some features have a delayed definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the code `"---` you are using an shortcut of package `babel`.

To get them to work you need to use this shortcuts after `\begin{document}`!

The following code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\newcommand\foo{% <=========================== uses babel shortcuts!
  qwe "--- rty%
}

\foo

asd "--- fgh

\end{document}
```

gives the wished result:

[image]