# Spaces around Cyrillic emdash (babel)

Tags: spacing, babel, punctuation, cyrillic, russian

There is the command `"---` (Cyrillic emdash) defined in the *babel* package (for the Russian language). It is shorter than the usual English dash `---` and has shorter spaces around it (also they are non-breaking as I can see). What is the width of such spaces? Is it equal to the width of the `\,` space?

Comment: Could you please add your code and an image? I did not understand well what you ask.

Comment: @Sebastiano See [_babel-russian_ package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-russian).

Comment: See at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139748/cyrillic-em-dash-is-rendered-inconsistently or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344829/russian-em-dash-in-macros. I think that these are similar at your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\cyrdash` is responsible of printing the dash; when the current language is Russian, it prints character 22 (the same slot as the em-dash, but in T2A encoded fonts it is shorter) or does

```
\hbox to 0.8em{--\hss--}
```

when the current encoding is not T2A, which means it superimposes two en-dashes so that the overall width is 0.8em (so changing with the font). The definition of `"-` is a bit complicated:

```
\declare@shorthand{russian}{"-}{%
  \def\russian@sh@tmp{%
    \if\russian@sh@next-\expandafter\russian@sh@emdash
    \else\expandafter\russian@sh@hyphen\fi}%
  \futurelet\russian@sh@next\russian@sh@tmp}
\def\russian@sh@hyphen{\nobreak\-\bbl@allowhyphens}
\def\russian@sh@emdash#1#2{\cdash-#1#2}
\def\cdash#1#2#3{\def\tempx@{#3}%
\def\tempa@{-}\def\tempb@{~}\def\tempc@{*}%
 \ifx\tempx@\tempa@\@Acdash\else
  \ifx\tempx@\tempb@\@Bcdash\else
   \ifx\tempx@\tempc@\@Ccdash\else
    \errmessage{Wrong usage of cdash}\fi\fi\fi}
\def\@Acdash{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
  \cyrdash\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}%
\def\@Bcdash{\leavevmode\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi
 \nobreak\cyrdash\penalty\exhyphenpenalty\hskip\z@skip\ignorespaces}%
\def\@Ccdash{\leavevmode
 \nobreak\cyrdash\nobreak\hskip.35em\ignorespaces}%
```

Basically it means that `"-` produces `\russian@sh@hyphen`, whereas `"--` does `\russian@sh@emdash`.

The former issues `\nobreak` so the preceding word part can be hyphenated; then inserts a discretionary hyphen, allowing the following word part to be hyphenated.

The latter looks at the next two tokens (the first is still `-`); there are four cases according to the third character

1. `"---` issues `\@Acdash`;
2. `"--~` issues `\@Bcdash`;
3. `"--*` issues `\@Cdash`;
4. None of the above, so `"--` is followed by (ignored) spaces and another token than `-`, `~` or `~`.

In the fourth case the error `Wrong usage of cdash` is raised.

- The case `"---` removes a preceding space if present and, in this case, inserts a nonbreaking space of width 0.2em, followed by `\cyrdash` and a further nonbreaking space of width 0.2em.
- The case `"--~` removes a preceding space if present, inserts `\cyrdash` and then a penalty like for an explicit hyphen, ignoring following spaces.
- The case `"--*` is for “dialogues”: no space before and the `\cyrdash` is followed by a space of 0.35em, ignoring following spaces.

There is an error in the definitions: `"---` at the beginning of a paragraph can produce unexpected results. There should be `\leavevmode` at the beginning like for the other two macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

%% fix the error
\makeatletter
\def\@Acdash{\leavevmode\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
  \cyrdash\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|"-|: a"-b

\verb|"---|: a"---b a "--- b

\verb|"--~|: a"--~b a "--~ b

\verb|"--*|: "--*a "--* a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Is `0.2em` more or less than the width of the `\,` space?

Comment: @Constructor In text mode, `\,` does `\thinspace` which inserts a 0.16667em kern.

Comment: One correction. `\cyrdash` is provided in the Russian Language Definition File for the case if `\cyrdash` is not defened elesewere. In particular `\cyrdash` is defined in `T2A` and some other cyrillic encodings and points to a slot in font files from LH bundle.